# Restriction Dynamic Currency Discount (DCC) Singapore and New Zeland

Tags: application

In reference to the patent: [CA2383173C](https://www.google.com/patents/CA2383173C)

Is there any restriction in using this patent in Singapore or New Zeland? Thank you in advance for any reply.

Answer (score 0):

This is a Canadian patent, which does not apply outside of Canada. However, according to [WIPO](https://patentscope.wipo.int/search/en/detail.jsf;jsessionid=178F80380B6CC09472DED3A4F9AF10A6.wapp2nA?docId=WO2001004846&recNum=1&tab=NationalPhase&maxRec=&office=&prevFilter=&sortOption=&queryString=), there appear to be equivalent patents in New Zealand (NZ 517105) and Singapore (SG 2002000131).

[IPONZ](http://www.iponz.govt.nz/app/Extra/IP/Mutual/Browse.aspx?sid=635930033358881771) appears to show that NZ 517105 is still in force.

[IPOS](https://www.ip2.sg/RPS/WP/CM/IPDetailsPTP.aspx?AppNbr=vW8gDYPhgCRtRm7HF37Qjl0xIvXnre57w1gnS%2bJ%2b%2f7k%3d) appears to show that SG 2002000131 is still in force.

Accordingly, it seems that you are not free to use the claimed subject matter of these patents.